# How to deal with undefined api requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on the website I am creating depending on what username the user enters to pull data from, one API request may come back as undefined. I was wondering if there is a way to handle this to just output blank data rather than crashing the whole site.

the api request:

```
await axios.get(this.state.url+'match/'+this.state.username+'/'+this.state.accountId).then(response => this.setState({Match: response.data['matches']}));
```

Handling the data from the request:

````
import './MatchHistory.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import axios from 'axios';

  const MatchHistory =  ({ history }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>
           {history.map(hist => (
            <Card>
              <img src={'img\\'+hist.lane+'.png'}></img>
              <li key={hist.gameId}>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Lane:{hist.lane}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Role:{hist.role}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Champion:{hist.champion}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">GameId:{hist.gameId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Kills:{kills}</h5>
              </li>
            </Card>
      ))}}
        </p> 
      </div> 
   )
  }

      export default MatchHistory;```
````

Comment: Can you share full code and error message ?

Comment: Need a bit more information to help. Can you share the source and full error? Or a link to a repro?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the card with an if statement like below:

```
const MatchHistory =  ({ history }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>
           {history.map(hist => (
           if(hist || hist!=null || hist!=undefined){
              <Card>
              <img src={'img\\'+hist.lane+'.png'}></img>
              <li key={hist.gameId}>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Lane:{hist.lane}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Role:{hist.role}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Champion:{hist.champion}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">GameId:{hist.gameId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Kills:{kills}</h5>
              </li>
            </Card>
           }

      ))}}
        </p> 
      </div> 
   )
  }
```

Comment: When i try wrapping the card within the if statement, its giving an error saying expression expected

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same code, just include validation on history variable using lodash

```
import './MatchHistory.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash'

  const MatchHistory =  ({ history }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>
           {!_.isEmpty(history) && history.map(hist => (
            <Card>
              <img src={'img\\'+hist.lane+'.png'}></img>
              <li key={hist.gameId}>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Lane:{hist.lane}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Role:{hist.role}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Champion:{hist.champion}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">GameId:{hist.gameId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Kills:{kills}</h5>
              </li>
            </Card>
      ))}}
        </p> 
      </div> 
   )
  }
```